# R - Purrr - Apply Function to Tibbles in List

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr

I need some help applying a function to four tibbles individually stored in the same list.

Function:

```
status_fun <- function(Status,
                       Escalated,
                       Created,
                       Resolved
                       ){
  if(Escalated == "Yes"){
    return("Escalated")
    } else if(Status == "Closed" && (month(Created) == month(Resolved) || Resolved - Created < 5
              )
    ){
      return("Closed")
    } else {
      return("Not Solved")
    }
}
```

I have a list with 4 tibbles inside of different sizes.
I simply want to apply the function above that uses four columns to each tibble, but I'm getting all sorts of errors. I've searched as much as I can and read R4DS and other posts here, but I can't find a solution.

```
dummy %>%
   map(., status_fun)
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : 
 argument "Escalated" is missing with no default

dummy %>%
   map(~ map(., status_fun))
Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : 
  argument "Escalated" is missing with no default
```

The following returns a list with only one value, which I'm not interest in, I want a list with four tibbles with the same dimensions (rows) as the input

```
dummy %>%
   map(., ~ status_fun(Status = 'Status', Escalated = 'Escalated', Created = 'Created', Resolved = 'Resolved'))
[[1]]
[1] "Not Solved"

[[2]]
[1] "Not Solved"

[[3]]
[1] "Not Solved"

[[4]]
[1] "Not Solved"
```

The dummy list is the following:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 589 x 5
   Created    Resolved   Status      Country    Escalated
   <date>     <date>     <chr>       <chr>      <chr>    
 1 2020-04-03 2020-04-08 Closed      Luxembourg No       
 2 2020-03-31 NA         In Progress France     No       
 3 2020-03-31 NA         In Progress France     No       
 4 2020-03-31 NA         In Progress Luxembourg No       
 5 2020-03-31 NA         In Progress Luxembourg No       
 6 2020-03-30 NA         In Progress France     Yes       
 7 2020-03-27 NA         In Progress Ireland    No       
 8 2020-03-27 2020-04-10 Closed      Luxembourg No       
 9 2020-03-27 NA         In Progress Luxembourg No       
10 2020-03-27 2020-03-30 Closed      Ireland    No       
# ... with 579 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 316 x 5
   Created    Resolved   Status               Country    Escalated
   <date>     <date>     <chr>                <chr>      <chr>    
 1 2020-04-13 NA         Open                 Luxembourg No       
 2 2020-04-13 NA         Open                 Spain      No       
 3 2020-04-07 NA         Open                 France     No       
 4 2020-04-03 NA         In Progress          Luxembourg No       
 5 2020-03-30 NA         Awaiting Information Luxembourg No       
 6 2020-03-30 NA         Awaiting Information France     Yes       
 7 2020-03-30 2020-03-31 Closed               France     No       
 8 2020-03-30 NA         Awaiting Information France     No       
 9 2020-03-30 NA         Awaiting Information Spain      No       
10 2020-03-30 NA         Awaiting Information Sweden     No       
# ... with 306 more rows

[[3]]
# A tibble: 64 x 5
   Created    Resolved   Status               Country Escalated
   <date>     <date>     <chr>                <chr>   <chr>    
 1 2020-04-13 NA         Open                 Chile   No       
 2 2020-04-10 NA         Open                 Mexico  Yes      
 3 2020-04-10 NA         Awaiting Information Mexico  No       
 4 2020-04-09 NA         Open                 Chile   No       
 5 2020-04-03 2020-04-06 Closed               Mexico  Yes       
 6 2020-04-02 2020-04-02 Closed               Mexico  No       
 7 2020-04-01 2020-04-01 Closed               Mexico  No       
 8 2020-03-31 2020-04-01 Closed               Brazil  No       
 9 2020-03-30 2020-03-31 Closed               Mexico  No       
10 2020-03-27 2020-04-06 Closed               Mexico  No       
# ... with 54 more rows

[[4]]
# A tibble: 30 x 5
   Created    Resolved   Status      Country Escalated
   <date>     <date>     <chr>       <chr>   <chr>    
 1 2020-04-13 NA         Open        Chile   No       
 2 2020-04-07 NA         Open        Brazil  No       
 3 2020-03-23 2020-03-25 Closed      Chile   No       
 4 2020-03-17 2020-03-18 Closed      Chile   No       
 5 2020-03-16 NA         Open        Mexico  No       
 6 2020-03-11 2020-03-11 Closed      Brazil  No       
 7 2020-03-11 2020-03-12 Closed      Brazil  No       
 8 2020-03-10 2020-03-10 Closed      Brazil  No       
 9 2020-03-09 NA         In Progress Brazil  No       
10 2020-03-02 2020-03-03 Closed      Brazil  No       
# ... with 20 more rows
```

**What am I missing?**
I've tried all sorts of pmap, map_2, the instructions here [Code not working using map from purrr package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009016/code-not-working-using-map-from-purrr-package-in-r)
and here [Apply function to nested loop (purrr package?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306749/apply-function-to-nested-loop-purrr-package)
with no success..
Thanks in advance for someone willing to take their time to solve my problem.

```
> version        _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.0                         
year           2020                        
month          04                          
day            24                          
svn rev        78286                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
nickname       Arbor Day  

packageVersion("tidyverse")
[1] ‘1.3.0’

packageVersion("lubridate")
[1] ‘1.7.8’
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that you are passing a single `data.frame` to a function that expects 4 arguments. To fix that you could change your function to:

```
new_fx = function (DF) {
Status = DF$Status
Escalated = DF$Escalated
...
}
map(dummy, new_fx)
```

The next potential issue is your use of `if ... else...`. Because this was not a reproducible example with expected output, I am assuming you want to add a column with the `if ... else...` statement. You will want to get rid of the double `&&` and `||` because they will evaluate to a single logical value.

Along with that, switch to using `ifelse` or, since you are in [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse), you could use `case_when()` would produce a vector of expected length.

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for the time it took you answer this question. Indeed the problem was in the function. I've amended it to include case_when as you described above and your assumption was correct, but I choose to include the dplyr::mutate inside the function to add the column.
Once again thank you for your time, I've learned something and the problem is solved.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can always accept this as the solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with mutating columns on several tibbles inside a list object, the below code worked on the problem above:

```
status_fun <- function(df){
  Escalated = df$Escalated
  Status = df$Status
  Created = df$Created
  Resolved = df$Resolved

  dplyr::mutate(df,
    Status = case_when(


      Escalated == "Yes" ~ "Escalated",


      (Status == "Closed" &


         (month(Created) == month(Resolved) | Resolved - Created < 5)) ~ "Closed",

      TRUE ~ "Not Solved"
    )
  )
}

dummy <-  dummy %>% map(., status_fun)
```